# "Chemical Lesson" or "Chemistry Lesson"?

Tags: adjectives, noun-phrases, attributive-nouns

When to use "**Adj+Noun**" & when to Use "**Compound Noun**"

Why saying "beautiful girl" but not "beauty girl"

And, "Chemical Lesson" or "Chemistry Lesson"?

Comment: Possibly because one studies *chemistry*, not *chemical*, hence the compound noun form.

Comment: When you see two nouns like _chemistry_ and _lesson,_ the first is a [_noun adjunct_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) that modifies the second. We actually _do_ see the phrase [_Beauty girl_](http://www.thebeautygirl.com/) in English, and that phrase follows the same rule. As for _chemistry lesson,_ please use your dictionary! What does "chemistry" mean?

Comment: Just some thoughts. Saying that *'a beautiful girl' is a girl who's beautiful* works (but *a beauty girl is a girl who's beauty* doesn't). Trying to say that *'a chemical lesson' is a lesson that's chemical* doesn't work, so we wouldn't say *a chemical lesson*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. A counter example might be "glamorous girl" instead of "[glamour girl](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/glamour-girl)". We do say "glamour girl" but we wouldn't say "a girl who is glamour". It's a tricky thing to find a rule for.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we say "beautiful girl" but not "beauty girl"?

Think of the sentence combination "The girl is beautiful." + "She is coming this way now."  You can put them together by using **Adj+Noun"**:

*The beautiful girl is coming this way now.*

> And, "Chemical Lesson" or "Chemistry Lesson"?

Consider

*I have to go to my Chemistry lesson now* or *I have to go to my Chemistry class now*.

This is the same as saying *I have to go to my class about Chemistry now* or *I have to go to my class in Chemistry now*.

So, *Chemistry Lesson* is an example of using a **Compound Noun**.

Let's see if we can make it work as an **Adj+Noun"**.  Hmm.  Let's try the following two simple sentences: "I learned a lesson about Chemistry in the Kitchen today.  I learned that if you forget to put the milk back in the refrigerator, it goes sour and you have to throw it out."

In other words, *I learned a valuable chemical lesson today.*

That was a bit of a stretch.  It's much more common to use "Chemical lesson" as a **Compound noun**.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are saying. When you say 'beautiful girl' you are describing a girl who is beautiful. Hence adjective + noun is used. But if you say "chemical lesson" to mean studying/learning the subject of Chemistry, then it's wrong.

When you say "I have to finish my chemistry Lessons" **it means you have lessons related to the subject of Chemistry**. But if you say "I have to finish my chemical Lessons" it means you have lessons related to a chemical or chemicals.

Further examples:

> Thanks for the chemical lesson sadiq. (means, sadiq taught you something related to chemicals.)